Can I freely choose the spellcasting ability of Magic initiate, or is it tied to the spell list that I chose?
The wording of Magic Initiate in the new PHB24 is:

You gain the following benfits.
Two cantrips: you learn two cantrips of your choice from the Cleric, Druid or Wizard spell list. Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma is your spellcasting ability for this feat's spells (choose when you select this feat).

From that it isn't even clear to me that I do choose one of the lists. One could understand that it was allowed to choose one from the Cleric list, and one from the Druid list. The next paragraph however says:

Choose a level 1 spell from the same list you selected [...]

This means that I have to choose a list first, and afterwards I have to choose 2 cantrips from that list.
The text still doesn't specify wether I can choose freely wether Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma is my spellcasting ability for these spells, or wether this is linked to my choice of the Druid list, the Cleric list, or the Wizard list.
I would guess I can choose freely, because there isn't an unambigous mapping between the classes and the abilities. Is that the way it is intended?

You can choose freely from the three abilities
The Magic Initiate Feat lets you freely choose between Intelligence, Wisdom or Charisma as the spellcasting modifier, no matter which class you choose. That is how the the following sentence is to be understood:

Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma is your spellcasting ability for this feat's spells (choose when you select this feat).

As noted you choose one of those three, when you select this feat.  Contrast this with the 2014 version of the feat that stated:

Your spellcasting ability for these spells depends on the class you chose [..]

Which is clearly different, and ties the spellcasting ability to the chosen spell list. Further evidence for this is the fact that neither of the three classes in the 2024 version use Charisma as their spellcasting ability. Wizards use Intelligence and Clerics and Druids Wisdom, meaning the Charisma entry wouldn't make any sense if the ability was tied to the class.
One last thing I want to point out is the fact that you can repeat this feat, taking it multiple times and have to:

[...] chose a different spell list each time.

This is further evidence that you have to pick a specific spell list if you learn the feat, which you are able to take up to three times. You can however choose the same ability everytime, which most players will probably do, as most will just choose their highest ability of those three.

From design perspective, the 2014 is needlessly limiting. If you are a wizard, you will have a good intelligence but picking a spell for, say, a cleric means it'd be quite more limited. Yes, you don't have to choose something that takes your spellcasting ability into account but you're still limited. Being able to say you're a wizard who studied and understand a cleric spell enough to cast it (using your main spellcasting attribute) opens the door for much more utility.

@VLAZ: I wouldn't say the limitation is "needless".  It has narrative implications, like that Wizards can't simply study and learn cleric magic and cast them using their intelligence modifier.  (Only bards can do that via magical secrets using charisma, or things like healing word already being on their lists.  Artificers get cure wounds but the narrative flavour is intended to be potions or other technology, not pure arcane magic.)  2014 magic initiate seems intended for non-casters to pick up a bit of magic, hence the "initiate" name.  It also didn't allow using your own slots, only 1/day.

So now, in 2024, wizards can cast Healing Word with Int if they take magic initiate, a lot like it was a wizard spell. It's not, e.g. they can't choose it as their spell mastery at 18th level to cast it at will or apply some other class features.  And can't copy it into their spellbook to teach to other wizards as a wizard spell.  But it leaves less room for narrative explanation of "why not?"  (Being able to use your own spell slots is another huge buff to the feat vs. 2014, letting a wizard or sorc fill a backup-healer role.  That's presumably good for letting people play what they want.)

@PeterCordes Yeah I have a player in my group that loves playing wizards, but also wants to heal and she was overjoyed when I told her she can get a Healing Spell through Magic Initiate, once we transition to the 2024 rules.

@PeterCordes I do not find the need for this limitation. You're talking about narrative implications but somehow omit the full scope of it. A studious wizard can learn one spell (non-cantrip) you normally don't have access to. There is also the two cantrips which are supposed to be the simplest spells possible. So,the wizard that applies themselves can...cast less cleric spells than a 1st level cleric. That's hardly on-par with a bard. If anything it underlines how hard it is to cast spells that for others are just the intro to their teachings.
